# Create a textfield over MKAnnotation Callout Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, mkannotation

I'd like to make an editable callout, and from a quick look it seems like the best way is to create a textfield over it in the view.
So, I was wondering how to get the CGPoint of an annotation so that I can use it in placing my CGRect of a textfield. This is the code I'm using to display an annotation at a tapped point, how would one do the reverse?
If anyone suggests better ways to create an editable callout, I'm welcome to suggestions

```
 var point:CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.Map)

  EventLoc = self.Map.convertPoint(point, toCoordinateFromView: self.Map)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with Swift yet, but independent from the language, `MKMapView` has a method `convertCoordinate:toPointToView:` which you can use to convert a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to a `CGPoint`.

**EDIT**

From the [`MKMapView` reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/convertCoordinate:toPointToView:):

> Converts a map coordinate to a point in the specified view.

So in your case the last argument should be your map view:

> The view in whose coordinate system you want to locate the specified map coordinate. If this parameter is nil, the returned point is specified in the window’s coordinate system. If view is not nil, it must belong to the same window as the map view.

Comment: var TextCentre: CGPoint = self.Map.convertCoordinate(EventLoc!, toPointToView: x) I tried this, but I couldnt work out what to put for 'x'. The textfield always appeared in the top left of the screen.

Comment: When I used this in Obj-C, I had to put the map view there. So I assume it must be `self.Map`.

Comment: I've edited my answer with the relevant excerpt from the `MKMapView` class description.